# Doctrine Collection Entities not fully populated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I made a mapping of 4 entities, but when I view the objects in the collection , all objects are populated except the last. 
Here Entities

User.php

```html
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="icgo\AdminBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255,nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $name;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255,nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $surname;
 
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Affectation",mappedBy="user",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $affectations;
 
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->affectations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
 
...... getters and setters ....
```

Affectation.php

```html
/**
 * Affectation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="affectation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="icgo\AdminBundle\Repository\AffectationRepository")
 */
class Affectation
{
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="affectations",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uid",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
 
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="icgo\WorkPlaceBundle\Entity\Workplace",inversedBy="affectations",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wid",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $workplace;
 
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role",inversedBy="affectations",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rid",referencedColumnName="rid")
     */
    private $role;
 
.... getters and setters .....
```

Workplace.php

```html
/**
     * workplace
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="workplace")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="icgo\WorkPlaceBundle\Repository\WorkplaceRepository")
     */
    class Workplace
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;
     
     
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="wfa", type="string", length=1, nullable=false)
         */
        private $famille;
     
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nickname", type="string", length=255)
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\NotNull()
         */
        private $nickname;
     
        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="date")
         * @Assert\Date()
         */
        private $dateStart;
     
        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date_end", type="date")
         * @Assert\Date()
         */
        private $dateEnd;
     
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="label_short", type="string", length=255)
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\NotNull()
         */
        private $labelShort;
     
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="label_long", type="text")
         */
        private $labelLong;
     
        /**
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="icgo\AdminBundle\Entity\Affectation",mappedBy="workplace")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
         */
        private $affectations;
     
    .... getters and setters .....
```

Role.php

```
/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="icgo\AdminBundle\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label_short", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $labelShort;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label_long", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $labelLong;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Affectation",mappedBy="role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $affectations;

.... getters and setters ......
```

UserRepository.php

```
 class UserRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    {
        public function getUsers(){
            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u','a','r')
                ->addSelect('w')
                ->leftJoin('u.affectations','a')
                ->leftJoin('a.workplace','w')
                ->leftJoin('a.role','r')
                ->getQuery();

            return $query->getResult();

        }
    }
```

Result dump

[Dump image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31j8X.png)

As see, for the last object User , the table assignments, workplace and role objects are null. All the previous user are populated

Thanks for help

Comment: You've checked that those database records actually exist? A good test would be to turn your leftJoins into join & see if that record is still in your result set.

Comment: @Richard records exists in database. And  when turn leftjoin to join the result is the same.